# Autohotkey: How to escape % in a string?

Tags: autohotkey

I have script which should open the chrome.exe to show a webpage.

```
if WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
{   
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.
    WinMaximize  ; same
    Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe    "https://mobilex.personio.de/calendar/team-view?eventTypes=time_off%3D45700&status=all&departments=73561&preventScrollTop=true"
```

When I run this script I get:

[image]

So I think I need a way of how I could escape the % near 3D45700 in the URL above. Because when I remove the % the url gets called (unfortunately it won't work because the url is missing an important parameter).

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to this Autohotkey documentation

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked using ` for escaping a % in a string